# Missmatched types - expected opaque type, found a different opaque type

Tags: rust

I have two functions that both return the same opaque type.  Then a function that returns the same opaque type by calling either the first function or the second.  So, in total there are three functions all with the same opaque return type, however, when I try to compile, I get the following error:

> expected opaque type, found a different opaque type

Here is a sample construction:

```
pub struct Astruct {
    pub val: u64
}

fn build_iter_one<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<impl Iterator<Item=&'a Astruct>> {
    Some(list.iter())
}

fn build_iter_two<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<impl Iterator<Item=&'a Astruct>> {
    Some(list.iter())
}

fn select<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<impl Iterator<Item=&'a Astruct>> {
    let one = build_iter_one(list);
    
    if one.is_none() {
        build_iter_two(list)
    } else {
        one
    }
}
```

I would expect this to work since build_iter_one and build_iter_two both return the same opaque type.  The error message points to the two return types and says they are not the same.  What am I doing wrong?

I tried using the rust playground to build a simple version to no avail.

Comment: Compiler assumes that every `impl Trait` opaque type is different. Either name this type or use dynamic dispatch.

Answer (score 0):

The utility of returning opaque types is that you can change the actual return type without your callers noticing; the real type becomes an implementation detail. But your `select` function relies on the fact that two opaque types are identical which means you now can't change the actual type of either `build_iter_*` function without breaking `select`. But being able to change return types without callers breaking was the whole point of opaque types to begin with. That's why the compiler may not assume that two opaque types are identical.

As @Aleksander Krauze suggests, you'll either have to name the return types:

```
fn build_iter_one<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<std::slice::Iter<'a, Astruct>> {
//       this is the real type returned by `iter()`      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    Some(list.iter())
}

fn build_iter_two<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<std::slice::Iter<'a, Astruct>> {
    Some(list.iter())
}
```

This way, the compiler knows the types are actually identical.

Or you can use dynamic dispatch at the cost of an allocation and some runtime overhead:

```
fn select<'a>(list: &'a mut [Astruct]) -> Option<impl Iterator<Item=&'a Astruct>> {
    let one = build_iter_one(list).map(|iter| {
        // turn the opaque type into a trait object
        let b: Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &Astruct>> = Box::new(iter);
        b
    });
    // ...
    return one;
}
```

This way, it doesn't matter what types the `build_iter_*` functions actually return, as they'll be hidden behind the trait object.

Note that in either case, you'll run into borrowing issues due to the signatures you've chosen, but that is completely unrelated to the question at hand.